# Laravel 5.3 flash messages using laravel/flash package not working at all

Tags: laravel-5.3

i am new in laravel. i have some forms in my app that can be edited/updated, when the user updates infos in the form and click save i want a flash success message to appear, saying "successfully updated", and i want that for all my forms but it's not working. Can someone help me, please? i can't get where the problem is.
i followed this git to implemented flash msgs in my app [laravel/flash](https://github.com/laracasts/flash)

in my controller i have

```
 $this->validate($request, Other::$validationRules);

    $other = Other::findOrFail($id);
    $other->update($request->all());

    flash('sucessfully updated','sucess');

    return redirect('/profile/' .\Auth::User()->id. '/archives/other');
```

this is the flash msg on to of my edit form view

```
@if (session()->has('flash_notification.message'))
        <div class="alert alert-{{ session('flash_notification.level') }}">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

            {{ session('flash_notification.message') }}
        </div>
    @endif
```

in routes, i use route group web and auth middleware.

i hope i've been explicit enough.thanks

Answer (score 0):

or you could do like this

```
return redirect('/profile/' .\Auth::User()->id. '/archives/other')->with('message','sucessfully updated.');
```

and in view :

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
    <h2 style="color: green"><i class="fa fa-star"></i>{{Session::get('message')}}</h2>
@endif
```

Comment: laravel 5.3, as written in the question. it still doesnt work. is there any other configuration i'm yet to do to make it work? i really can't explain nor understand where the problem is.

Comment: if you could please install freshly laravel (5.3) again and try to use my code to see if it work or not ,maybe because you implement sth into you project and make it doesn't work.